# Emmet abbreviation setting for top option

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, emmet

When typing a style property name, the first option is almost always just the text I've typed already.
[image]
I can't find the setting to turn that off. (if there is one?) In my screenshot, it should list `font-size` as the first option. My editor scope is a vuejs single file component with stylus as the language.

In my settings I've done:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  "vue-html": "html",
  "vue": "html"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "vue-html": "html",
  "vue": "html"
},
```

I've also tried these to no avail:

```
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never",
"emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": false
```